# how to use py2exe with sucessive scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

So, I have several python scripts that are supposed to be executed one by one, some of them with various arguments, and the main script that executes them in the right order, something like this:

```
os.system('first.py')
os.system('second.py argument1')
os.system('second.py argument2')
os.system('third.py')
```

I want to make an .exe from the main script using py2exe. How do I tell py2exe that it needs all those scripts? I tried putting them into `options`:

```
options = {'includes':['first.py', 'second.py', 'third.py']}
```

...then into the list of scripts:

```
setup(console=[{'script':'main.py'}, 
               {'script':'first.py'}, 
               {'script':'second.py'}, 
               {'script':'third.py'}])
```

...but neither worked. py2exe creates a main.exe successfully, but when I launch it, it says:

```
"first.py" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable problem or batch file
```

Same with 'second.py' and 'third.py'.

Comment: try using `python first.py` instead of just `first.py` in os.system

Comment: nope, still the same problem

Comment: use exact path of python( where it is installed) i.e. `C:\python27\python.exe first.py` try this

Comment: now it says `C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in C:\\Python27`

Comment: Try adding location for python i.e. `C:\Python27` in python path env variable. Looks like because we have specified full path for that particular command it worked but generally to execute python it is looking for simple `python` command.

Comment: Also the location of your scripts also needs to be added in python path.

Comment: don't know if did it right (i added PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts' into system variables), but it didn't help

Comment: Yeah I think that is right.